# How to remove the Python Turtle Graphics window, and put the created turtle on the main window?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I explain, as you can see, I have a small window for creating a turtle. But as soon as I enter the name of the turtle 'name = turtleTurtle()', the Python Turtle Graphics window pops up. How to remove it and put the turtle on the main window?[image]

```
from pyclbr import Class
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from random import randint
import turtle
import time
import sys

class Main_WINDOW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('GOнки 1 - 8 player')
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1600,1200)
        self.setStyleSheet('.Main_WINDOW {background-image: url(project1.jpg);}')
        self.button()

    def button(self):
        addplayer = QPushButton('pop', self)
        addplayer.setGeometry(80, 60, 650, 55)
        addplayer.clicked.connect(self.F_addplayer)

        btn_zanavo = QPushButton('Заново', self)
        btn_zanavo.setGeometry(1100, 70, 400, 100)

        btn_delite = QPushButton('Удалить гонщика', self)
        btn_delite.setGeometry(80, 130, 650, 55)

        btn_start = QPushButton('start', self)
        btn_start.setGeometry(400, 930, 800, 50)

        l_name_game = QLabel('G O н щ и к', self)
        l_name_game.setGeometry(780, 162, 1000, 300)


    def F_addplayer(self):
        global Spisok
        Spisok = []
        foorma_spisok = ['arrow','turtle','circle','square','triangle','classic']
        coolor_spisok = ['green','blue','purple','gold']
        s_name, b_ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Выбор гонщика', 'Введите имя гонщика',)
        if b_ok:
             s_name = turtle.Turtle() 
             Spisok.append(s_name)
             s_forma, b_ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Выбор гонщика', 'Введите форму 
 гонщика', foorma_spisok, editable=False)
            if b_ok:
                s_name.shape(s_forma)
                s_color, b_ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, 'Выбор гонщика', 'Введите цвет 
гонщика', coolor_spisok, editable=False)
                if b_ok:
                    s_name.color(s_color)
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print('Гонщик успешно добавлен!')
                else:
                    QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User have clicked "Cancel"')
            else:
                QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User have clicked "Cancel"')
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical('Canceled','User have clicked "Cancel"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_addplayer = QApplication([])
    add_player1 = Main_WINDOW()
    add_player1.show()
    app_addplayer.exec_()
```

I wanted the turtle to get up on the main window

Comment: `turtle` uses GUI framework `tkinter` which can't work with other GUIs

Comment: Does it work in any way?

Comment: not, `turtle` uses functions avaliable only in `tkitner`, and there is no method to embed tkinter's window/widget in PyQt's window. You would have to write own `turtle` from scratch.

Comment: if you want to draw shapes then you should do it without turtle - see example for PyQt4 [draw on canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pyqt4/draw-on-canvas)